# Unversion and add to ignore list not committing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a significant number of files that were accidentally added to my SVN source repository at one point.  Using the TortoiseSVN client, I went through and manually unversioned them from my working copy by right clicking, selecting "Unversion and add to ignore list" then selecting the extension (ex *.dll).

After completing this on hundreds of files, I now see them all in my "commit" dialog as "deleted".  No matter how many times I commit, they never get unversioned or disappear from the commit dialog.

I've tried checking out to a different location and the files that are supposed to be unversioned still check out.

Is there any way to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried checking out to a different location and the files that are
> supposed to be unversioned still check out.

I think that you haven't committed the changes (delete operation + new `svn:ignore` property). Or maybe you committed the changes into another folder in the repository (or even into another repository). Check the [revision history of your repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) and examine recent commits. Right now it's unclear what happens and maybe some screenshots will help.

> No matter how many times I commit, they never get unversioned or
> disappear from the commit dialog.

Commits in Subversion are atomic. If the commit is not going through then you will receive an error on the client side. So do you receive any errors when you commit the changes? Did you check the URL of your working copy? Maybe you made the commit into another directory?